# Generate constructor in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, constructor, eclipse-pdt

Is there any way to generate a constructor based on the class properties in Eclipse PDT?

Here is an example of how Netbeans does it:

[image: Netbeans constructor generator]

[image: Netbeans constructor generator]

Comment: I understand generating getters/setters but not constructors. I dont know what you could do via any kind of introspection with a constructor... Can you elaborate on what it needs to generate?

Comment: Hopefully with the Netbeans example (which I was using until now), my question will be more clear. Please ask if any further explanations are needed.

Comment: afaik this is not possible with PDT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor Generation was mentioned in [PDT 2.0 Plan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/2.0_Plan), but wasn't listed in the [PDT2.0 release notes](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/release-notes/pdt2_0.php) (or [the 2.1](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/release-notes/pdt2_1.php) for that matter).

So it is likely to be still missing.
Even the simple constructor completion (for the parameters) has [some mishaps recently](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156086/).